# How can i make some background in custom view

Tags: android, view, background, paint

How can i make some background in my custom view? I maked view-painter and i need to make backgroud with grid like in photoshop under my view, whitout driwing on my view's canvas. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the pattern to drawable folder which you want for background,

and call it in your Layout as

**android:background="@drawable/your_pattern"**

Comment: i dont have this attribute in my view =(

Comment: And i need to make background by my view but not for all layout

Comment: '@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.drawColor(backgroundColor); 
     this.setBackgroundDrawable(backGroundDrawable);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);  
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }'